# Why does right side of my laptop screen display appear black?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, repair, laptop-display

I have a HP laptop with Windows 7 as the OS. I don't know why but since some time the right side of the  display looks black. It looks like this:

[image]

And, I think if you zoom on, you can see that the taskbar at the bottom is slightly raised and below it you can see the top of the display!

Whatever I do, whatever application I open it won't occupy that black region.

I don't know how it happened. It wasn't like this before. Maybe somebody (some relative of mine perhaps) decided to try something crazy and screwed up. But here it is..

I want to know how it could''ve happened and, more importantly, how I can fix this. Suggestions?

Comment: Try adjusting the resolution in your `Display Settings`.  **Right Click** anywhere on the desktop and select `Screen Resolution`.  From there you should be able to mess with the sizes until it fits your screen right.

Comment: @CheesusCrust, checked that. It's already the maximum resolution possible.

Comment: If possible, provide a picture of what you are seeing.  As this would help us troubleshoot it a little more.

Comment: @CheesusCrust, picture added.

Comment: First things first: get a wetwipe, or bleach, and clean that laptop!

Comment: "maximum possible" may not be the *correct* resolution. Google the model of the laptop and look for "native resolution" it will probably be 720p so in the neighborhood of 1280 x 720 @ 16:9 aspect. your screencap looks like 4:3 aspect

Comment: @Yorik, but as I said earlier the laptop did not have any "black region". Then too the display was of the same resolution it is now. So can you clarify how the problem can be due to the resolution of the screen?

Comment: Does this problem occur only inside Windows or is the black region there even when the system is loading?

Comment: @Mokubai, yeah ;D

Comment: @Witiko, it's there even when the system is loading. It's there the whole time when I shut  down the laptop. While booting up, it appears when the "*Welcome*" phrase appears on the screen.

Comment: There are a few things about the screenshot that suggest you are using the wrong resolution: 1) the icons look to be normal (not stretched or squashed); 2) the date and time appear to be displayed at the lower right suggesting that the desktop area is not being clipped; 3) the desktop area is set to a 4:3 aspect ratio but your LCD screen is not 4:3 aspect ratio. Again, the "highest possible resolution" you select may not be the correct one for the monitor. LCD monitors have a native resolution. I suspect you have the wrong one set.

Comment: One additional place to check: some laptops have function keys to switch external monitor output. Check for that functionality

Comment: @Yorik, Didn't need to google. System information of the pc says that the resolution is 1024 × 768 × 60 Hz. And the display is already set to exactly that.

Comment: Windows Update may have "updated" your monitor drivers for you.  You might want to check when your drivers were installed and try to rollback to an earlier driver.  You may end up just having to search for and install the correct ones outside of Windows Update.

Comment: Without editing the image, if I select the desktop area only, copy that and then resize that copy to 1024px, I get slightly more than 768px high. If I do the same with the screen area, and size that to 1600, I get approximately 1000. This is 16:10 aspect. Considering foreshortening, it is probably 16:9. In any event 1024 x 768 is not going to be the native resolution.

Comment: You can check this yourself with a ruler: measure the width, divide by 16 and multiply that result by 9. Start over and divide by 4 and multiply by 3; and repeat again with 16 and 10. Whichever one gives you the correct height is the one you have.